Implementation of OpenMP iterator in task depend clause
I’m trying to adapt the code of the block matrix multiplication (example 5.3.5) in C + OpenMP using tasks.
This code illustrates task dependencies using depend on array sections.
Here is an excerpt of the official example:

void matmul_depend(int N, int BS, float **A, float **B, float **C) {
    int i, j, k, ii, jj, kk;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i+=BS) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j+=BS) {
            for (k = 0; k < N; k+=BS) {
                // Note 1: i, j, k, A, B, C are firstprivate by default
                // Note 2: A, B and C are just pointers
                #pragma omp task private(ii, jj, kk) \
                    depend ( in: A[i:BS][k:BS], B[k:BS][j:BS] ) \
                        depend ( inout: C[i:BS][j:BS] )
                for (ii = i; ii < i+BS; ii++ )
                    for (jj = j; jj < j+BS; jj++ ) {
                        for (kk = k; kk < k+BS; kk++ )
                            C[ii][jj] = C[ii][jj] + A[ii][kk] * B[kk][jj];
                    }                
            }
        }
    }
}

I wanted to use iterator instead, so as to see if makes any difference in performance.
Here is my adaptation of the above code with iterator.
void matmul_iter(int N, int BS, float **A, float **B, float **C) {
    int i, j, k, ii, jj, kk;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i+=BS) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j+=BS) {
            for (k = 0; k < N; k+=BS) {
                #pragma omp task private(ii, jj, kk) \
                    depend (iterator (i1 = i:i+BS-1, j1 = j:j+BS-1, k1 = k:k+BS-1),  in: A[i1][k1], B[k1][j1] ) \
                        depend (iterator (i1 = i:i+BS-1, j1 = j:j+BS-1), inout: C[i1][j1] )
                for (ii = i; ii < i+BS; ii++ )
                    for (jj = j; jj < j+BS; jj++ )
                        for (kk = k; kk < k+BS; kk++ ) {
                            assert(ii < N && kk < N && jj < N);
                            C[ii][jj] = C[ii][jj] + A[ii][kk] * B[kk][jj];
                        }
            }
        }
    }
}


However, i observed weird segmentation faults depending on the size of the matrix (N) and the blocksize (BS). This is true for both gcc-13 and clang-18. For small values, e.g N=64 and BS=8, 16 or 32, the program runs fine and produces the right result. I scripted the compilation+execution for different combinations of N and BS and found that :

with gcc, the greatest value without segfault was N=90 and BS=6.
with clang, each time BS=2 i have an assertion failure, the rest just segfaults

Assertion failure at kmp_taskdeps.cpp(594): dep_list[i].flag == 0x1 || dep_list[i].flag == 0x2 || dep_list[i].flag == 0x3 || dep_list[i].flag == 0x4 || dep_list[i].flag == 0x8.
OMP: Error #13: Assertion failure at kmp_taskdeps.cpp(594).
OMP: Hint Please submit a bug report with this message, compile and run commands used, and machine configuration info including native compiler and operating system versions. Faster response will be obtained by including all program sources. For information on submitting this issue, please see [https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/.](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/)

So, my question i am wrong in the use of iterators or is the implementation of iterators in gcc and clang incorrect?
I join hereafter the whole source code for sake of reproducibility.

#include <assert.h> 
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_VAL 3
#define M 100
#define MS 4
#define ERROR 1.e-20
#define HYPERTHREADING 1

// Assume BS divides N perfectly

void matmul(int N, int BS, float **A, float **B, float **C) {
    int i, j, k, ii, jj, kk;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i+=BS) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j+=BS) {
            for (k = 0; k < N; k+=BS) {
                for (ii = i; ii < i+BS; ii++ ) {
                    for (jj = j; jj < j+BS; jj++ ) {
                        for (kk = k; kk < k+BS; kk++ ) {
                            C[ii][jj] = C[ii][jj] + A[ii][kk] * B[kk][jj];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void matmul_depend(int N, int BS, float **A, float **B, float **C) {
    int i, j, k, ii, jj, kk;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i+=BS) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j+=BS) {
            for (k = 0; k < N; k+=BS) {
                // Note 1: i, j, k, A, B, C are firstprivate by default
                // Note 2: A, B and C are just pointers
                #pragma omp task private(ii, jj, kk) \
                    depend ( in: A[i:BS][k:BS], B[k:BS][j:BS] ) \
                        depend ( inout: C[i:BS][j:BS] )
                for (ii = i; ii < i+BS; ii++ )
                    for (jj = j; jj < j+BS; jj++ ) {
                        for (kk = k; kk < k+BS; kk++ )
                            C[ii][jj] = C[ii][jj] + A[ii][kk] * B[kk][jj];
                    }                
            }
        }
    }
}

void matmul_iter(int N, int BS, float **A, float **B, float **C) {
    int i, j, k, ii, jj, kk;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i+=BS) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j+=BS) {
            for (k = 0; k < N; k+=BS) {
                #pragma omp task private(ii, jj, kk) \
                    depend (iterator (i1 = i:i+BS-1, j1 = j:j+BS-1, k1 = k:k+BS-1),  in: A[i1][k1], B[k1][j1] ) \
                        depend (iterator (i1 = i:i+BS-1, j1 = j:j+BS-1), inout: C[i1][j1] )
                for (ii = i; ii < i+BS; ii++ )
                    for (jj = j; jj < j+BS; jj++ )
                        for (kk = k; kk < k+BS; kk++ ) {
                            assert(ii < N && kk < N && jj < N);
                            C[ii][jj] = C[ii][jj] + A[ii][kk] * B[kk][jj];
                        }
            }
        }
    }
}


int main() {
    float **A = calloc(M, sizeof(float *));  
    float **B = calloc(M, sizeof(float *));
    float **C = calloc(M, sizeof(float *)); 
    float **C_dep = calloc(M, sizeof(float *)); 
    float **C_iter = calloc(M, sizeof(float *));  

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        A[i] = calloc(M, sizeof(float));
        B[i] = calloc(M, sizeof(float));
        C[i] = calloc(M, sizeof(float));
        C_dep[i] = calloc(M, sizeof(float));
        C_iter[i] = calloc(M, sizeof(float));
    }

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            A[i][j] = rand() % MAX_VAL + 1;
            B[i][j] = rand() % MAX_VAL + 1;
        }
    }
    printf("initialisation\n");

    double time_ref, time_dep, time_iter, speedup, efficiency;

    time_ref = omp_get_wtime();
    matmul( M, MS, A, B, C);
    time_ref = omp_get_wtime() - time_ref;
    printf("Time ref ------ : %3.5lf\n", time_ref);

    time_dep = omp_get_wtime();
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp single
        matmul_depend(M, MS, A, B, C_dep);
    }
    time_dep = omp_get_wtime() - time_dep;
    printf("Time depend --- : %3.5lf\n", time_dep);

    time_iter = omp_get_wtime();
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp single
        matmul_iter(M, MS, A, B, C_iter);
    }
    time_iter = omp_get_wtime() - time_iter;
    printf("Time iter ----- : %3.5lf\n", time_iter);
    
    speedup = time_dep / time_iter;
    efficiency = speedup / (omp_get_num_procs() / (1 + HYPERTHREADING));
    printf("Speedup ------- : %3.5lf\n", speedup);
    printf("Efficiency ---- : %3.5lf\n", efficiency);

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            if (fabs(C_dep[i][j] - C_iter[i][j]) > ERROR) {
                printf("Bad results :-(((\n");
                printf("C[%d][%d]=%lf C_dep[%d][%d]=%lf C_iter[%d][%d]=%lf\n", i, j, C[i][j], i, j, C_dep[i][j], i, j, C_iter[i][j]);
                for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
                    free(A[i]);
                    free(B[i]);
                    free(C[i]);
                    free(C_dep[i]);
                    free(C_iter[i]);
                }
                free(A);
                free(B);
                free(C);
                free(C_dep);
                free(C_iter);
                exit(1);

            }
        }
    }

    printf("OK results\n\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        free(A[i]);
        free(B[i]);
        free(C[i]);
        free(C_dep[i]);
        free(C_iter[i]);
    }
    free(A);
    free(B);
    free(C);
    free(C_dep);
    free(C_iter);

    return 0;
}

I observe weird segmentation faults despite it compiles fine with gcc and clang.
I was expecting the same behavior than with the official example using array sections.


Declare loop variables in the loop header: for ( int i.... then you don't have to worry about private. 2. It's not necessary to give depend clauses for variables that are only input.


Where you write C[i:BS][j:BS] you want C[i:i+BS][j:j+BS] probably.

Thanks @Victor but you point at the depend with array section which is the official example of the spec. When using array section, the syntax is array [lower-bound : length], while with iterators, you describe the range of values with lower and upper bounds.

You're right. Lower+length.

For clang, this is a compiler bug. I would assume that the case is similar for gcc. https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/pull/99347 should fix the issue for clang. Note, that the upper bound is exclusive, so you should use i1 = i:i+BS to cover all elements of the block. Considering the runtime overhead, I would try to avoid such excessive use of dependencies if not really necessary.
